# Complicated scope with sql injection issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

in my Rails app I have a scope that looks like this:

```
  scope :organization_join, -> (organization_type) {
    organization_table_name = organization_type.underscore.pluralize
    joins("LEFT JOIN \"#{organization_table_name}\"
      ON \"#{organization_table_name}\".\"organization_id\" = \"survey_reports\".\"organization_id\" AND
         \"survey_reports\".\"organization_type\" = '#{organization_type}'"
    )
  }
```

This scope allows sql injection attack...
What will be the best way to rewrite this to be secure of sql injection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got two problems here:

- You take in an argument for a type that's converted to a table name and not tested against a white-list of valid table names.
- You inline potential user data in your query.

What you could do to solve the first is vet the table name against a list of valid names:

```
ORGANIZATION_TABLES = %w[
  team
  club
  house
]

scope :organization_join, -> (organization_type) {
  case (organization_type)
  when *ORGANIZATION_TABLES
    _table = organization_type.underscore.pluralize
    joins(
      "LEFT JOIN %s ON %s.%s = %s.%s",
      _table,
      _table, :organization_id,
      :survey_reports, :organization_id,
    ).where(
      survey_reports: { organization_type: organization_type }
    )
  else
    raise "No idea what #{organization_type} is."
  end
}
```

Here I've switched part of your join clause to a standard `where` which allows using the built-in escaping functions. Second, because none of those column or table names are reserved words, you don't need to go through the trouble of escaping them with quotes.

You may find this is all completely redundant if you can simply do this:

```
scope :organization_join, -> (organization_type) {
  includes(:survey_reports).where(survey_reports: { organization_type: organization_type })
}
```

If you have a proper `has_many` relationship, this allows eager loading with an implicit join.

Comment: This is a very clean answer.